# Call to a member function extension() on null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
public function store(Request $post){

    $messages = ['brand'=>'Brand not included','logo'=>'Image not included'];

    $post->validate(['brand'=>'required|unique:brands|max:20',
                    'image'=>'nullable|nimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg|max:2048'],$messages);

        $brandsId = $post->id;
         if($brandsId){
            $brands = Clients::find($brandsId);
            if($post->hasFile('photo')){

                $file = time().'.'.$post->logo->extension();
                $post->logo->storeAs('public/uploads/images',$file);
                $brands->logo = 'storage/uploads/images/'.$file;
            } 
        }else{
            $file = time().'.'.$post->logo->extension();
            $post->logo->storeAs('public/uploads/images',$file);
            $brands = new Brands();
            $brands->logo = 'storage/uploads/images/'.$file; 
         }
        $brands->brand = $post->brand; 
        $brands->save();

        return response()->json($brands);
        
}
```

When I edit the file I get this error C:\wamp64\www\StockCrud\app\Http\Controllers\BrandsController.php

Comment: Do u get an error or does it just give you the file with no context?

Comment: What is your question? The error message you get is crystal clear. It tells you that $post->logo is `null`. Probably not what you expected.

Comment: When editing a file, it gives this error, and the image name is not displayed